# A visit to the ancient city Rome

Tags: word-choice

Should it be "A visit to the ancient city of Rome"? Because "A visit to the ancient city Rome" doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Where did you see this? Why are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "of" is normally required.

I can imagine those two words being adjacent only in an appositive:

> [Philosophy and the City: Classic to Contemporary Writings](https://books.google.ca/books?id=XvKhRSTnm4oC&pg=PA6&dq=%22ancient%20city%20rome%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D5kaVbrSJ4bBggT4nYGgBw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22ancient%20city%20rome%22&f=false)- Page 6
>   Sharon M. Meagher
>
> We now leap forward in our story to the time of the decline of
>   **another great ancient city, Rome.**